# I have remove all xml tags only expect <bold> and <italic>

Tags: c#

I have written this code for removing all tags(not data). But I need code for removing all tags except bold and italic tags.
Is there any conditional replace for that?

rtbVerificationBox.Text = Regex.Replace(rtbVerificationBox.Text, @"<(.*?)>", "");

Comment: I would strongly advise you to use an XML API to deal with XML, rather than trying to do it with regular expressions.

Comment: If this is user input, I'd strongly suggest that you should be looking to *accept* only tags you consider valid and *reject as invalid input* anything else, rather than attempting to sanitise it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's regex to match all tags except `<b>` and `<i>`

```
<([^bi]*?)>
```

https://regex101.com/r/f1hOgg/1

Comment: Unless you've got other elements that start with `b` or `i`. It doesn't match `<ignore>` for example. Fundamentally, using a regex for this is going to be *much* harder than using an XML API.